TYPO3 indexed search fails to index PDF files
I'm hoping to get help with a problem I can't solve. The working environment is as follows:
SYSTEM

Debian 12 bookworm
PHP 7.4 (tried 8.2 and 8.3 with failure on crawler) + FPM/FastCGI
/usr/bin/pdftotext and /usr/bin/pdfinfo installed
openbase dir with: /usr/bin

TYPO3 v.11.5

Indexed search engine 11.5.38
site crawler 11.0.7
bootstraP package
12.0.10 (all ext are installed correctly)

TYPO3 settings (setup)

page.config.index_enable = 1
page.config.index_externals = 1

Admin tools > settings > extensions configuration
INDEXED SEARCH

Path to PDF parsers /usr/bin
PDF parsing mode: 0
Full Text Data Length 0
Enable metaphone search (sounds like) 1
Ignore Extensions jpg,gif.jpeg,html
Debug mode: checked
Max External files: 99
Use "crawler" extension to index external files unchecked

SITE CRAWLER configuration

base site: https://domain.it/
php path: /usr/bin/php


ROOT PAGE OF THE SITE
I have tried numerous configurations to try to index pdfs, such as:

FilePath - with path configured: fileadmin and depth: 4 levels below

Limit to extensions (commalist) pdf (To avoid other files like doc,
rtf, etc.)

Database recordswith table: file



THE PROBLEM
I see that the instructions on the TYPO3 website are not very updated in the screens and that in some ways they are insufficient. I understood that even if the "crawler" extension is not installed, at each update of the page, carried out NOT from the active backend (I assume with another browser) TYPO£, INDEXED SEARCH parses the page, extracts the words it deems useful for the indexing, then reads the links and indexes them too; about PDFs you should open them one by one, inspect them with pdftotext/pdfinfo and from the resulting text obtain other keywords to index the document.
Therefore I tried every way, even launching the crawler manually, first filling the queue, then defining the process, and launching it observing the progress percentage.
Indexing occurs ONLY for pages, via the crawler (launched by hand) or by visiting the site.
From Web > Indexing > (root page):

List: Pages - indexed statistics show only indexed contents (type, date, etc.) but no pdf files
List: External documents - list always empty
Detailed statistics -> overview - all pages listed but no related or listed pdfs

Test

indexed search configuration: Use "crawler" extension to index external files set to 1 or less things do not change
by chance I discovered, by typing the keyword "pdf" in the search box, I see 6 indexed files to which no new ones are added despite the repeated tests carried out above. Even worse, these files are duplicates, i.e. the output is: document1-1-12.pdf (referring to pages 1-12) document1-13-25.pdf (pages 13-25) etc.

DEBUG AND LOG
Debug activated or not, nothing is showed or registerer
inspecting /web/typo3temp/var/log/*.log I can't find any entry valid to understand whats happens
site error log is ok without errors
?
I hope to find some help, thank you very much

This issue seems to be related to EXT:crawler and also seems to be an known issue there:
https://github.com/tomasnorre/crawler/issues/1057
Maybe consider to switch to EXT:ke_search
